# how to get date information based on row data in excel as shown in image?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

[image: Data frame for reference]

[Error image after using Byrow function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQmRJ.png)

I would like to get the start and end dates based on the row data information, which is their attendance on daily basis. Is there any formula which could really help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *Start Date*:

`=BYROW(F2:S6,LAMBDA(ζ,XLOOKUP(1,0/ζ,F1:S1,,-1,1)))`

Same for *End Date*, though changing the last parameter from 1 to -1.

Comment: Thank you Jos, But when I tried the same, it is showing name error #NAME?

Comment: You tagged `office365`, so of course I presumed you had access to the function `BYROW`. Can you clarify?

Comment: yes I have office365

Comment: But not the `BYROW` function?

Comment: not sure! Actually for the first time I here this function

Comment: Type =BY into a random cell and see if that function comes up in the intellisense dropdown.

Comment: No it is not coming

Comment: So just use `=XLOOKUP(1,0/F2:S2,F$1:S$1,,-1,1)` in D2 and then copy down.

Comment: Woooah! now it works for start date, but unfortunately end date is not shooting up properly. Can you help me on that

Comment: Figured it! thanks very much for the help :). Have a great day ahead.